# Zend Framework with Smarty 3

Tags: zend-framework, smarty, smarty3

How do I configure Smarty 3 in Zend Framework?
I have no idea what to put in application.ini and Bootstrap.php

Comment: Hi, this has been discussed before. for example take a look at http://devzone.zend.com/406/integrating-smarty-with-the-zend-framework/ It's quite old but will give you a rough overview. cheers

Comment: Thank you @simplyray :) do you have another sample ? Thank you very much :D

Comment: added better tutorial as answer

Answer (score 0):

Good step-by-step tutorial regarding smarty3 for zend:
http://gediminasm.org/post/smarty-3-extension-for-zend-framework

Next time you might try to search the web (www.google.com) for tutorials/topics regarding your problems *before* asking here. If then you hit a special (detail) problem, ask here. Take a look at http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/